# Comparing Text entered into the textbox of a windows form to objects in order to validate user

Tags: c#, list, winforms

I want to call a List from another class in order to compare text thats enter into a windowforms textbox. The list contains emails and passwords retrieved from a database using a select procedure already, I just want to compare the text for a text box to it in order to validate user login. I'm lost when it comes to doing this , please help. I searched the goggle and couldn't find anything.

Here's the creation of the list from the original class

```
 List<UserModel> IDataConnection.CreateUserList()
        {
            List<UserModel> output;
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString("MasterChef")))
            {
                output = connection.Query<UserModel>("spPeople_GetLogin").ToList();

            }
            return output;
        }
```

this is the other class and what I did so far. I called it and want to use it to validate login by seeing if the text entered into the text box match any of the elements

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
    {
        List<UserModel> output = GlobalConfig.Connection.CreateUserList();

        public LoginForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        

        private void logButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ValidateLogin())
            {
              
            }
        }

        private bool ValidateLogin()
        {
             bool valid = true;

            if (loginEmailTextBox.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                valid =  false;
            }
            if(loginPasswordTextBox.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                valid |= false;
            }
            return valid; 
        }
    }
}
```

I searched all of google , watched youtube videos and everything.

Comment: `bool exists = output.Any(um => um.Email == loginEmailTextBox.Text && um.Password == loginPasswordTextBox.Text)`? Or use `SingleOrDefault()`? -- Did you hash / salt the Passwords? -- You should pass the Controls' content to the `ValidateLogin()` method

Comment: no I didn't has the passwords. I'm trying to keep it really basic and simple.